# Javascript / Ajax works in Mozilla firefox but not in Google Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a form which works for both registration and login and am using javaScript Ajax to submit it.

It is working fine in Mozilla firefox but fails in Chrome and IE.

I'm trying to execute a AJAX and PHP script that checks database with email id in the text box. If email id already exists in database it shows password field(Login) otherwise other mandtatory fields. ie name and phone number(Register).

My main problem is that this part is not working.

```
document.getElementById("contbtn").style="display:none";
document.getElementById("subbtn").style="display:block";
```

Here is the javaScript Ajax code:

```
<script>
function CheckUser()
{
    var uemail = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var xmlhttp;    
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
var frm_element = document.getElementById('contbtn');
var vis = frm_element.style;

if (vis.display=='' || vis.display=='none') {
    vis.display = 'block';
}
else {
    vis.display = 'none';
}

var frm_element1 = document.getElementById('subbtn');
var vis1 = frm_element1.style;

if (vis1.display=='' || vis1.display=='none') {
    vis1.display = 'block';
}
else {
    vis1.display = 'none';
}
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","check_user.php?emlid="+uemail,true);
    xmlhttp.send();

}
</script>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<ul class="contactform">
<li><label>Email</label><input name="email" id="email" required="" onblur=" return CheckUser();" type="text"></li>
<div id="txtHint"></div>
<li>
<input class="btn" id="contbtn" onclick="CheckUser();" type="button" value="Next" style="display: block;">
<input class="btn" id="subbtn" style="display: none;" type="submit" value="Submit">
</li>
</ul>
</form>
```

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using? The Ajax call seems to work for me. Are you sure it's not an error in your PHP?

Comment: Version 37.0.2062.124 dev-m

Answer (score 1):

To actually answer the question why it was not working:

`style` is a property of `HTMLElement` which can not be overwritten. (It's protected). In your first example you tried to do this by doing `style = "string"`.

Style in JavaScript code however is an `object`, all `style attributes` are available as `object attributes`. Difference between CSS-code and JavaScript are the dashes. Separate words get a dash `-` in CSS-code and are concatenated in JavaScript by `camelCasing`, e.g.: `border-width` in CSS-code becomes `borderWidth` in JavaScript.

So to correctly set or retrieve style attributes in JavaScript treat `style` as an object. e.g:

1. `Element.style.display = "block"`
2. `Element.style.borderBottomColor = "#ff0000"`

Answer (score 0):

I made it work just replaced THIS

```
    document.getElementById("contbtn").style="display:none"
    document.getElementById("subbtn").style="display:block";
```

WITH

```
var frm_element = document.getElementById('contbtn');
var vis = frm_element.style;

if (vis.display=='' || vis.display=='none') {
    vis.display = 'block';
}
else {
    vis.display = 'none';
}

var frm_element1 = document.getElementById('subbtn');
var vis1 = frm_element1.style;

if (vis1.display=='' || vis1.display=='none') {
    vis1.display = 'block';
}
else {
    vis1.display = 'none';
}
```